# How to listen and connect multiple ports with python?

Tags: python, server, connection, port

I'm working on a program that's basicly sending/recieving messages but I want to make a ranking system. The admins of this program can inform each other as well as the other users. I read so many articles already but I can't find the solution. Can anyone help me?
Here is the code for the server:

```
import socket,threading

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=9134
PORT2=2233
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST,PORT))
server.bind((HOST,PORT2))
server.listen()
clients=[]
nicknames=[]

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)


def handle(client):
    while 1:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            print(f'{message}')
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index=clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()

            nickname=nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():
    while 1:
        client, adress=server.accept()
        print(f'Connected with {str(adress)}')

        client.send("NICK".encode('utf-8'))
        nickname=client.recv(1024)
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        broadcast(f'{nickname} connected to the server!\n'.encode('utf-8'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()
        print(clients,nicknames)

print("Server is running")

receive()
```

Comment: Why does `handle()` assume that if there's an error while broadcasting, that the problem is with this client?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Actually I can't even write this code. I searched too much but I'm not able to write the code. When I try to bind and listen 2 different ports like;
server.bind((HOST,9134))
server.bind((HOST,9133))
taking this error "OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied"

Comment: You have to use multiple sockets to listen to multiple ports. Each socket can only be bound to one port. But why do you think you need multiple ports?

Comment: I want multiple ports for private communication like the admins of the program can communicate each other and users of the program can communicate each others. If I don't need to listen multiple ports for that task what should I do?

Comment: Use one port along with authentication. When someone authenticates, you know whether they're an admin or ordinary user.

Comment: Oh ok, ypu helped me so much thanks :)